# trying to upload a image to my server from android

Tags: java, android, image, apache

am using this code to upload an image to my web server:

```
    public void send (View view)
    {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        DataInputStream inputStream = null;

        String pathToOurFile = "sdcard/yo.jpg";
        String urlServer = "http://192.168.1.4/uplaod.php";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile));

            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Allow Inputs & Outputs
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            // Enable POST method
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile + "\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            Log.i("ODPOWIEDZ", serverResponseMessage);
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            Toast.makeText(context, "its here 1 ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            Toast.makeText(context, "its in catsh", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i("WYJATEK", ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

and i get this message from my LogCat where is the problem here ??

59-124/system_process D/SntpClient﹕ request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

this is my php file

```
<?php
    $target_path  = "uploadedfile/";
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded";
    } 
    else {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SNTP` error relates to the time protocol, which, incidentally has nothing to do with your app. It looks like it's just the emulator trying to fetch the latest timestamp off an `ntp` server. Just discard it.

The issue is still something else. You did notice that there might be a typo in the name of the `php` script? In your code you refer to it as `uplaod.php`.

Also, make sure you have enabled internet access in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: thanks for the notice 
i just modified the php file name , everything works fine from the app but still  i didn't find my image in the server 
do i need a specific configuration in the server ,if so what do you recommend ?

Comment: I would check the webserver logs, they often reveal much more than what you think may be happening. Also, make sure that php error logging on-the-page is turned on.

Comment: You are not using the DataInputStream. Start with determining the response from the php script. The script echo()'s information. Now you do not see it. Grab it. Add more echo statements to the script. For instance check if the upload directory exists and echo.